# HTML table- border not showing when running flask app

Tags: python, html, css, flask, virtualenv

I am running a simple flask application using a virtual environment and everything was working well until I couldn't get the html borders to show. Had a friend look it over that knows some html and he couldn't figure it out.

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///test.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable = False)
    data_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="../static/css/main.css">
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="content">
    <h1>Task Master</h1>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>Added</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yeet</td>
            <td>yah</td>
            <td>
                <a href="">Delete</a>
                <br>
                <a href="">Update</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

main.css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

I am using Windows & running flask app through visual studio code. I'm assuming it may be a complication with flask? I have no idea how to fix this issue and have looked at other posts but nothing has worked.

Edit: for clarification the text appears and links are clickable, the text is just somewhat mushed together in the left corner with no borders for the table.

Comment: Are you trying to add `border` to just the `table` or to table-row `tr` and table-data `td` also?

Comment: A screenshot of how the table is rendered in the browser would help. But I would say that is not related to Flask, but rather with the HTML, CSS or even the Browser (maybe adjust the zoom or characters size? ) So ye try different browser. Also @Alex Bota answer should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this code to your stylesheet

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Do table borders not get automatically rendered?

Comment: No, you need to specifically style them

Answer (score 1):

1. Try different Browser.

Also try this:

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}
```